# Add a custom attribute when retrieving a model

Tags: php, laravel

Is possible to attach a custom attribute when retrieving a model in laravel?.

The problem is that I need to return some data that is not in the database along the info from the database. I've been doing it manually but I guess that there might be a way to do it in the model.

Example: I have an application table. Each application contains a folder with documents with the same application id. I need to attach the amount of files the folder that correspond to each application.

This is what I do:

```
$application = Application::get();
$application = $application->map(function($a){
    $a->files = $this->getFiles($a->id); // This gets the amount of files
    return $a;
})
```

Is there some way to do it in the model in a way that `$application->files` is already contained in `$application` when doing `Application::get()`

Comment: You"re looking for `protected $appends = []` property on the model.

Comment: @JagjeetSingh it retrieves the files on the server from a folder with the same id as the application. but I did it using the answers and the `$appends` prop. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function getFooBarAttribute()
    {
        return "foobar";
    }
}
```

And access to that attribute like:

```
$user->foo_bar;
```

or like,

```
$user->fooBar;
```

More detailed documentation;
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Answer (score 1):

in the Application model

```
public function getFilesAttribute()
{
    return 'lala'; // return whatever you need;
}
```

now application model has an attribute named `files`.

```
$application->files // returns lala.
```

example code.

```
$applications = Application::get();
$application_files = applications->map->files;
```

official documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor